# Use cookies coming from Node.JS on port 8080 when developing with React.JS on port 3000

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I generated a react application using create-react-app, and I run it on port 3000 (localhost:3000) when I develop.

The React App calls APIs exposed by a Node.JS server running on port 8080 (localhost:8080). The Node.JS server exposes login APIs, and it sets some cookies.

If I build the React App, and I deploy it on the public folder of the Node.JS server everything works fine.

When I run the React App with:

```
npm start
```

I can't use the cookies coming from Node.JS server after performing the login since they're coming from a different url (different port).

Did someone experience this issue?

Comment: You can add a proxy in the dev server.

Comment: Thank you @JJin I created a proxy including this line in my react project package.json "proxy": "http://localhost:3001/", which redirect all the APIs requests to the node server. Problem solved